# simple transparent proxying for windows xp

Tags: windows, proxy, portforwarding

I have a server running at http://localhost:9080 but the http clients are sending the requests
to http://localhost:80.

Do you know a good way to redirect traffic from port 80 to port 9080? My OS is WinXP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a nice port forwarding tool [here](http://www.quantumg.net/portforward.php) that should do the trick.

Comment: That is not transparent, it is a simple tcp portforwarder.

Comment: @MaXX, looks like what the questioner was looking for, though. Maybe you can suggest something else?

Answer (score -1):

It is possible to redirect ports easily with a SSH clients like PuTTY.
But you need a SSH server, therefore I'm not sure it can be a solution for you ?

Comment: No, it also weren't transparent, it were only a tcp portforwarder.

Comment: Peter: sorry to contradict you, with putty it's transparent.